# Update one field in sphinx RT index

Tags: php, sphinx

Is it possible to update only one field out of two in sphinx sql or in PHP? for example the below is the index that I have

```
+-----------+---------+
| Field     | Type    |
+-----------+---------+
| id        | integer |
| article   | field   |
| notes     | field   |
| post_date | uint    |
| gid       | uint    |
+-----------+---------+
```

and then I'm inserting this

```
insert into artidx values (1, 'test article', 'note one', 1234,1);
```

Then this, which is updating "article" just fine but removing "notes",

```
replace into artidx (id, article) values (1, 'test article modified');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Not possible.

To **update** a field, need to delete the whole record and re-insert it.

The `REPLACE INTO` command, just does this in one step.